# Mongo bulk insert and avoid duplicate values for multiple keys

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections `items` with 120,000 entries and `itemHistories` with more than 20 million entries. I periodically update all `items` and `itemHistories` by fetching an API that lists all `history` data for an item.

What I need to do is batch insert the history data to the collection while avoiding duplicates. Also the history API returns only `date`, `info`, `item_id` values.

Is it possible to batch insert in Mongo so that it doesn't add duplicates for 2 values combined (date, item_id). So if there already is an entry with the same `date` and `item_id` don't add it. Basically the `date` is an unique index for the `item_id`. It's allowed to have duplicate `date` values in the collection but only if the `item_id` is different for all the duplicates.

One item can have close to a million entries so I don't think fetching the history from the collection and comparing it to the API response is going to be optimal.

My current idea was to add another key to the collection called `hash` that is an `md5(date,info,item_id)` and make it an unique index. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit of digging in the documentation of Mongoose and MongoDB I found out that there is a thing called **Unique Compound Index** that solves my problem and answers this question. Since I've never used indexes before I didn't know such a thing was possible.

> You can also enforce a unique constraint on compound indexes. If you
>   use the unique constraint on a compound index, then MongoDB will
>   enforce uniqueness on the combination of the index key values.
>
> For example, to create a unique index on groupNumber, lastname, and
>   firstname fields of the members collection, use the following
>   operation in the mongo shell:

```
db.members.createIndex( { groupNumber: 1, lastname: 1, firstname: 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

Source: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-unique/

---

In my case I can use this code below to avoid duplicates:

```
db.itemHistories.createIndex( { date: 1, item_id: 1 }, { unique: true } )
```